# xgboost does not display information even when silent = False

Tags: python, xgboost

I am using `xgboost` to train a model. I want it to print out some info about training process. However, it does not give me anything even if silent = False.

```
import xgboost as xgb
xgbc = xgb.XGBClassifier(
   gamma=0.1, learning_rate=0.05, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=8,
   min_child_weight=6, missing=None, n_estimators=250, nthread=8,
   objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
   scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=False, subsample=0.9)

xgbc.fit(X, y)
```

xgboost package version:
0.6

python version:
2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may find more help with this on [XGBoost's github](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost). You should probably just open a ticket and include all of your config. The guys managing the repo should be more readily available to help with XGBoost-specific problems than most SO users. Cheers!